# Go: serving http directory with subdirectories

Tags: linux, go, filesystems

I have file server hierarchy

```
/tmp/core/css/*.css 
/tmp/core/js/*.js 
/tmp/apps/someapp
```

I have two locations for static files /tmp/core and /tmp/apps accordingly.
Following code works but allow to serve directory /core without subdirectories. 
To serve each subdirectory in /tmp/core/something I need to specify http.Handle for that.

Is it possible to specify it easier with one definition of http.Handle ?

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp/apps/someapp"))) 
http.Handle("/core/", http.StripPrefix("/core/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp/static core/"))))
```

Comment: I don't understand the question .. can you rephrase ? what is the problem? you want to force to specify a handle for each sub directory?

Answer (score 2):

This simple snippet serves the contents of my `go` folder and everything within.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/Users/sergiotapia/go")))
}
```

---

Visit `localhost:8080`.

This serves my files in the `go` folder and every subdirectory and file within. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Try running the snippet above and set the path to a folder on your drive.

Comment: I have different location for static files, in case if only one location used "/" everything works but I need for two different locations.

Comment: In that case, what you're doing is the right way to do things. See the official example here: http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer - specifically the `Example (StripPrefix)`. This way you have multiple handlers serving multiple URL paths.